# Oracle SQL - How to display all categories and total number of values referenced each category

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with one column that serves as a foreign key and references to the other table.

I have one table labeled as Product

```
    ID NAME         CATEGORYID  PRICE
   --- -----       ----------- ----------
 1 Apple             1           .5
 2 Banana            1           .69
 3 Watermelon        1           2.99
 4 Cereal            1           3.99
 5 Large Chips       1           2.99
 6 Small Chips       1           .99
 7 TV                2           699
 8 Phone             2           499
 9 Computer          2           899
10 Laptop            2           1099
11 Headphones        2           39
```

And the other table as

```
    ID NAME
------ -----------------
 1 Food
 2 Electronics
```

"Category ID" is a foreign key that references to "ID" in the "Category" table. What I'm trying to do is display the second table as well as the total number of products that belong to each category.

For example the Total Number for Category Id 1 is 6, and Category 2 is 5.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.  This is a pretty basic SQL query.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment (exam, whatever). That is OK, but you must show what you have tried, what worked and what didn't work, what you found difficult or confusing, etc. Just seeing someone else's solution with a trivial join, group by and select count(*) won't help you at all - perhaps it will get your hw done, so what? Still not learning much from it. It will help you a lot more if you try on your onw, then report here what worked and what didn't work.

Comment: So you haven't attempted anything?

Answer (score 1):

you need a simple `join` with `group by`:

```
select ct.id as category_id,
       ct.name as category_name,
       count(pr.id) as number_of_products
from category ct 
     join product pr on ct.id=pr.category_id
group by ct.id,ct.name
```